# How can I optimize this Mysql query with bad performance?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table named 'activities' with 50M+ rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `activity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_of_contract` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration_s` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp_end` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp_start` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_of_room` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`),
  KEY `analyse` (`id_of_room`,`timestamp_end`,`timestamp_start`,`duration_s`),
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have this request:

```
select  *
    from  activities
    where  id_of_room=3263
      and  timestamp_end>1471491882747
      and  timestamp_start<1479267882747
      and  duration_s>900
    order by  duration_s desc;
```

The explain return this:

```
id  select_type table       partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      activities  NULL        range   analyse         analyse 18      NULL    1       5.00        Using index condition; Using filesort
```

The query returns in 1.5s. How can I optimize this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ORDER BY` takes a long time... why do you need to order?

Comment: how many records does this return?

Comment: @e4c5 it returns 1k rows

Comment: pease also note that my comment and the other comment were with in minutes of your question so I don't know if the flood situtation (which I am sorry to hear about) applies in thsi situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construct: `end > 1471491882747  and  timestamp_start < 1479267882747` is essentially impossible to optimize, primarily because the Optimizer does know know whether there could be overlapping rows.

`INDEX(id_of_room, duration_s)` *may* make it run faster.  If used, it would filter on `id_of_room` and `duration_s`, but more importantly, it would avoid the filesort.  Not knowing the distribution of the values I (and the Optimizer) cannot predict whether this index will be better.  And it is likely to be better for some values and worse for others.

One slight benefit would be to change `BIGINT` to `INT UNSIGNED` or maybe even `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` *where appropriate*`.  With 50M rows, shrinking the data will decrease I/O.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of RAM.

A potentially big help is to avoid `SELECT *`.  List only the columns you need.  If that list is short enough, then devise a composite, *covering*, index.

One final way to speed up the query is with 'lazy eval':

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM ( SELECT activity_id
        FROM activities
        where  id_of_room=3263
          and  timestamp_end>1471491882747
          and  timestamp_start<1479267882747
          and  duration_s>900
         ) AS x
    JOIN activities AS a  USING(activity_id)
    ORDER BY  a.duration_s desc;
```

This will be beneficial *if* using a covering index for the derived table *and* lots of rows are filtered out.  In this case, it is worth trying *this* ordering of index columns:

```
INDEX(id_of_room, duration_s, timestamp_start, timestamp_end, activity_id)
```

Comment: pretty good answer +1 but looks like the question is already abandoned.

Comment: no response from OP for two comments and two answers.

Comment: @e4c5 - Maybe OP posted question just before "leaving for the day".  And we don't know what timezone and whether it is a 'work' question.  Anyway, by the time I have read a question, I am usually eager to provide an answer; I don't stop to notice that it might be futile.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose

Comment: @e4c5 Firstly, my office is under water today so I have other thing to manage. Secondly, I need à little time to benchmark all thoses solutions and select the most accurate one. I never abandonned my questions and always upvote the better answer.

Comment: Good to know you don't abondon your questions. the standard practice is to accept the best one and upvote other good ones.